# Change height of a div based on available height using only CSS

Tags: html, css

This is what I want http://jsfiddle.net/QsLMh/9/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="filter">
</div>
<div class="body">
    <div class="data">
    </div>
    <div class="data">
    </div>
    <div class="data">
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
  margin:5px;
  height:300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header{
  margin:5px;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid green;

}
.filter{
  margin:5px;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.body{
  margin:5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  height:100%;
  max-height: 70px;
}
.data{
  margin: 10px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

As you can see if you click on filter div the body div doesn't automatically resize. I can do this with JavaScript but I wonder if it's possible to do so using the only CSS?

Comment: You cannot assign a click event with css.

Comment: i dont want a click event i want my body div to have full available height in any case.

Comment: Have you tried height:100% ?

Comment: It is not clear to me exactly what you want. If you want what is in the fiddle, why not use that code? What exactly is your issue?

Comment: i want the last div (body) use all available height! no matter how many other div are visible. in the fiddle when you hide filter div the last div height doesnt change.